# How to assign custom keyboard shortcuts to Preview app on Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to assign a keyboard shortcut to the "Blank Page" menu item in Preview on Mac OS X Yosemite. Keyboard shortcuts on Mac are easy to assign, so I thought it would just work:

[image]

But it doesn't work. I try assigning to other menu items like "Adjust Size…". No luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You can overcome this issue by saving your shortcuts under "All Applications" rather than saving them specifically to "Preview.app". As a side effect, this will affect other applications with the same menu names.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a shortcut to keyboard you have to insert in the menu title the exact name of the menu command you want to add. And, in Preview App, Blank Page doesn't exists as menu.

As an example, watching the image below, you must fill menu title with `New from Clipboard`, `Open...`, `Open Recent`, etc.

[image]